# How to make a function to use dict keys as variables to a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I would like to know how I can create a function that converts the keys of a directory as variables for the class, For intance

```
class Example():
   DICT={
   'spam0':1,
   'spam1':2,
   'spam2':3,
   ...
   }
   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       My_special_function(self, kwargs)  #This is my question

   def output(self):
       print(self.spam0, self.spam1, self.spam2)

x=Example()
x.output()
1 2 3
```

**NOTE**

The defined dictionary may vary in size

Comment: You mean you want class `Example` to have variable `spam0` with value 1? why? It's better to leave it as a dictionary.

Comment: @Guy Because I could define and modified my variables all at once.

Answer (score 5):

You could use

```
self.__dict__.update(DICT)
```

in `__init__` (where `DICT` is accessible to `__init__`; in your example you would use `Example.DICT` instead)

I sometimes use this technique to avoid explicitly defining a big amount of instance variables. However it's a bit hackish and probably best avoided in most cases. For example, it will make your class more difficult to understand for others reading your code.

(Note that this technique will create instance variables, not class variables. Creating class variables like this is even less recommended, due to increased potential for name collisions and other confusion)

Answer (score 0):

I saw this code, but I don't know why it works, but actually I would rather make my own to learn and understand better python.

```
import inspect
import itertools as it

def filtered_locals(caller_locals):

    result = caller_locals.copy()
    ignored_local_args = ["self", "kwargs"] 

    for arg in ignored_local_args:
        result.pop(arg, caller_locals)
    return result

def merge_dicts_recursively(*dicts):
    '''
    Creates a dict whose keyset is the union of all the
    input dictionaries.  The value for each key is based
    on the first dict in the list with that key.

    dicts later in the list have higher priority

    When values are dictionaries, it is applied recursively
    '''

    result = dict()
    all_items = it.chain(*[d.items() for d in dicts])
    for key, value in all_items:
        if key in result and isinstance(result[key], dict) and isinstance(value, dict):
            result[key] = merge_dicts_recursively(result[key], value)

        else:
            result[key] = value
    return result


def digest_config(obj, kwargs, caller_locals={}):
    """
    Sets init args and CONFIG values as local variables

    The purpose of this function is to ensure that all
    configuration of any object is inheritable, able to
    be easily passed into instantiation, and is attached
    as an attribute of the object.
    """

    # Assemble list of CONFIGs from all super classes

    classes_in_hierarchy = [obj.__class__]
    static_configs = []
    while len(classes_in_hierarchy) > 0:
        Class = classes_in_hierarchy.pop()
        classes_in_hierarchy += Class.__bases__

        if hasattr(Class, "DICT"):
            static_configs.append(Class.DICT)


    # Order matters a lot here, first dicts have higher priority
    caller_locals = filtered_locals(caller_locals)
    all_dicts = [kwargs, caller_locals, obj.__dict__]
    all_dicts += static_configs
    obj.__dict__ = merge_dicts_recursively(*reversed(all_dicts))



class Example():
   DICT={
   'spam0':1,
   'spam1':2,
   'spam2':3
   }
   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       digest_config(self, kwargs)

   def output(self):
       print(self.spam0, self.spam1, self.spam2)
```

Comment: @Jussi Nurminen